# Vim undocumented side effect when using a numeric value instead of a flag when doing replacement?

Tags: vim

While experimenting with Vim substitutions I noticed that something like `s/\w*/(&)/2` behaves like `0,2s/\w*/(&)`. In other words having a numerical value where the g or i or c flags would be(or no flag at all), acts as the max limit of a range affecting the first match on every line.

E.g. running both versions of the above would produce the same output on the text below

```
alpha
beta
gamma
```

to

```
(alpha)
(beta)
gamma
```

However going through the Vim docs for s_flags as well as searching online I do not see this mentioned somewhere. Has anyone else come against this before and/or is there a perfectly normal explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From :help :s,

```
:[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]
            ...
            When [count] is given, replace in [count] lines,
            starting with the last line in [range].  When [range]
            is omitted start in the current line.
            ...
```

In other words, your 2 is a count, not a flag.  It is not clear from this doc that the space is optional, but it seems to be (and I would not relish the job of rewriting it to make that clear).